# Differentiable and Not Continuous

Tags: real-analysis

Find a function $f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ that is differentiable at one point and not continuous at any other point.

Answer (score 1):

The function $f(x)=\begin{cases} \ \ \ x, \  x\in\mathbb Q\\ -x, \ x\not\in\mathbb Q\end{cases}$ is continuous at $x=0$ **only**.
Do you see why? Is this function differentiable at $x=0$? Why? Can you change it so that is differentiable at $x=0?$ Find one such that $f'(0)=0$.

Comment: Here is a form of intuition for this particular example: You can view $f(x)$ as a superposition of two functions, interspliced.  The only way the function can be continuous at a point is if both functions are approaching the same value there.  The only way a derivative can exist is if the derivatives of both functions are approaching the same things.